# Hover on div and show other div but hidden div is out side of main container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i was trying to show a div on hover which is out side the main container, i find mostly codes about showing a div which is just inside the main container, but i want to show and hide a div which is out side of main container

[Check Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/BC4eY/2/)

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
    }
                    ,function(){
                        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        
});
```

this fiddle is working for hovering a div and show div which is inside it, but how can we do it for a div and the other is also outside of main div

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1910/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could possibly do this with CSS only if your div is adjacent instead of inside:

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1920/)

## css

```
    div.overlay { opacity:0; -webkit-transition:opacity 500ms ease; transition:opacity 500ms ease;}
    div.box:hover ~ div.overlay,
    div.overlay:hover {    opacity:1; height:100%;}
```

## html

```
<div class="box">Info about a game</div>
<div class="overlay"> Play </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `.overlay` is the only `div` with that class, you can just use :

```
$('.overlay').fadeIn()
```

or

```
$(this).siblings('.overlay')
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BC4eY/1921/)**

Comment: just to be pesky ;] when using this type of solution I'd recommend always stopping the queue.. as in: $(this).siblings('.overlay').stop(false,false).fadeIn(); or (false,true) which ever suits you better.. do this also for the fadeOut().. If you don't and you hover on and off a bunch of times, you'll see the element keep appearing/disappearing.

Comment: @webkit, thanks for the suggestion, I was aware the weird flickering effect. Added `stop()` to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can change this code:

```
$(this).find(".overlay");
```

To this:

```
$(this).parent(".overlay")
```

Or if the the only class you have overlay, just use:

```
$('.overlay)
```